# Bert Supervised model topics per class with only one class

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, topic-modeling, sentence-transformers

I am trying to use BERT Supervised model for topic modeling. I dont have the liberty to use `topic_model = BERTopic(verbose=True)`. I have to download the pre-trained model locally and use it.
I have around 80 documents with manual labels, having 5 categories.
Distribution of categories are something like this

| Category | Number of Samples |
| --- | --- |
| A | 40 |
| B | 18 |
| C | 10 |
| D | 5 |
| E | 6 |

I am fitting the transform using

```
topics, _ = topic_model.fit_transform(docs, y=targets)
```

When I run `topic_model.get_topic_info().head(10)`, I see only one class distributed across all topics.

I have tried using `sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2`, `sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L12-v2`, and `sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2`

I realize that I have a very small training set. How can I optimize further?